# Consulta SQL a Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Necesito esta consulta en eloquent porfavor, nose como usar Join

$colegio=DB::select('select colegio.id, colegio.nombre as colegio, comunas.nombre as comuna from colegio
inner join comunas on colegio.id_comuna = comunas.id where colegio.id='.$request->get("idcolegio").'')[0];

intente con

$colegio = DB::table('colegio')
->where('id' , .$request->get("idcolegio").'')[0]);

Comment: intente con:
$colegio = DB::table('colegio') ->where('id' , .$request->get("idcolegio").'')[0]);   pero nose como meter JOIN

Comment: No se si de esta manera este bien:         $colegio = DB::table('colegio')
        ->innerjoin('comunas', 'colegio.id_comuna', '=', 'comunas.id')
        ->select('colegio.id','colegio.nombre','comunas.nombre')
        ->where ('colegio.id='.$request->get("id").'')[0];

Comment: Por su puesto, pero el error es el siguiente                                                                         Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::innerjoin()

Answer (score -1):

Es necesario revisar la documentación de Eloquent.
A continuación, un ejemplo de código de tabla Usuario y Roles para usar Join:

```
$usuarios = User::from('users as u')
    ->join('roles as r',function($join){
        $join->on('u.roles_id','=','r.id')->where('r.estado','=',1);
    })    
    ->select("u.*","r.nombre")
    ->where('u.estado','=',1)
    ->get();
```

También puedes realizar una consulta personalizada completa, de la siguiente forma:

```
DB::select('SELECT id FROM roles WHERE id = ?', [1]);
```